# Best way for binding socket.io?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am a new guy on NodeJs and Socket.io, I have three cases when binding socket events

**case 1:**

```
socket.on('getUsers', function() {
// my logic here
});
```

**case 2:**

```
socket.on('getUsers', function(){
  getUsers(socket);
});

function getUsers(socket) {
 // my logic here
}
```

**case 3:**

```
// module user.js
module.export = {
 getUsers: getUsers
}

function getUsers(socket) {
  // my logic here
}    

...

var userModule = require('user.js');
socket.on('getUsers', function(){
  userModule.getUsers(socket);
});
```

Is there any differences between three cases? 
Does the case #3 consume less memory than the others when I have thousands of socket?

Comment: No meaningful difference in performance or execution.  Just different ways of structuring/organizing the code.  It's totally up to you which makes the cleanest organization of your code.

Comment: I'm clear now, thank jfriend00